# Bootstrap dropdown searchbar closing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a dropdown searchbar on my site which closes when clicked. 
I'm trying to prevent this, but I can't find it myself.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">BrandName</a>
    </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>

      </ul>

      <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle hidden-xs pull-right" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
          <form class="navbar-form pull-right " role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zoeken">
        </div>
        </div>

      <div class="search-phone visible-xs" >
      <form class="navbar-form  " role="search">
        <div class="form-group search-phone2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zoeken">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
           </button> 
        </div>      
      </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I've tried different thing like this:
I don't know if this is the best way.

```
<script>

    $('.input.form-control').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        });

    </script>
```

But I can't find the solution.

Comment: can you provide some CSS, and/or a fiddle?

Comment: why did you add a dot in front of input? should be `$('input.form-control')` isn't it?

Comment: That's true! But this also doesn't prevent the searchbar to close.

Comment: Maybe you could try to add a `disabled` class to your dropdown. So it would be something like `class="xxxxxxxx disabled"`.

Comment: Instead of e.stopPropagation() try `e.preventDefault()`. If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. [Source](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: adding the `disables` class does not work. Also the `e.preventDefault()` doesn't do the job

Comment: Have you tried doing it custom instead of using the bootstrap syntax?

Comment: I'm still looking for the right answers.

I tried:

 '$('input.form-control').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        });'

        '$( 'input.form-control' ).click(function(){ return false; });'

        '$('input.form-control').click(function(){
      if($('#nav-searchform').hasClass('in'))
        $('#nav-searchform').collapse('hide');'

Comment: I found something, just checking if it works and I'll get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to make it work without any javascript involved. The bootstrap syntaxed needed a UL>LI dropdown in which you added the form instead of a button and a DIV. You seemed to be adding the search twice, but in my example, there is no need for that. The dropdown/search form follows and adapt with resizing, althought a bit of media query could fix a horizontal scroolbar showing on mobile resolution.

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/om1g7v0ZYh#)

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li>
                          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                              <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                              </div>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block submitBtn">Submit</button>
                          </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

css:

```
.submitBtn{
    margin-top:5px;
    background:#E7E7E7;
}

.submitBtn:hover{
    background:#DADADA;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
  .navbar-form{
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks IndieRok !! You Rock! =)

Comment: Glad I could help! It was my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instead:

```
   $('input.form-control').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oc60jLdb/

Comment: Here is an example live. http://www.superleuk.nl/  On small view (<786px) it is working, but that's not the dropdown i mean.